# Metrics on functions that use both the domain and range's metric.

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

If $(X, d_x)$ and $(Y, d_y)$ are metric spaces, then the metric on functions from $X$ to $Y$ is often defined as their supermum difference in $Y$. However, this only uses the metric on $Y$.

Can you construct a metric metric on the functions where small changes in both the domain *and* range result in small changes in the result? To be precise, we could say that

$$f = \lim_{(t_X, t_Y) \to (id_X, id_Y)} t_Y \circ f \circ t_X$$

One way I thought of is somehow comparing the graphs of two functions, but I did not get to far with that (average distance between points?).

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close this for the reason "unclear what you're asking". I think it needs to be made clearer what "interesting" means in this case. For what purpose are you using this metric?

Comment: @TheoBendit Well, I guess I wanted small changes in either the input or output would result in small changes in the metric. I think, you're right though.

Comment: @TheoBendit Also, lol, I voted to close, but it is still open despite me being the OP. Should I delete it instead?

Comment: I'm getting a better idea from your comment. If $X$ and $Y$ are bounded, then you could consider the Hausdorff metric on their graphs? That way, if the graph is "shifted" slightly (for metric spaces for which this has any meaning, e.g. the unit circle), the difference should be small in a way that doesn't depend on the function (i.e. the shifting map should be uniformly continuous).

Comment: @TheoBendit That might work. How would define the Hausdorff metric on a graph, though? A graph is a subset of $X \times Y$.

Comment: There's no canonical way, but pick a metric on $X \times Y$ that generates the product topology, and define it using that. I haven't worked it out, but I imagine it always generates the same topology.

Comment: @TheoBendit One thing I dislike about the Hausdorff metric though is that it is "lossy", so to speak. It only looks at worst case, not the average case, so to speak.

Comment: Here's an idea about how you could make this question more precise. You could formalise the idea of depending on $d_x$ by enforcing the map $T \mapsto f \circ T$ being uniformly continuous, where $T$ is a map from $X$ to $X$ that is uniformly continuous (maybe even lipschitz continuous?). That way, small perturbations on the domain will not cause great perturbations in the distances between functions.

Comment: Average is a tricky thing in a general metric space though. You could level the same criticism at the infinity norm as well. Unless you're going to stick some kind of measure on the space, I think you'll have trouble getting over that.

Comment: @TheoBendit Okay, I made an edit. How does it look?

Comment: Not quite punchy enough, I'm afraid. You really do need some kind of uniformity in the continuity. I'm afraid though that I can't continue with this any further right now though. Good luck!